# How to delete dynamically allocated pointer to pointer of int in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm trying to delete pointer to a pointer of integer which is dynamically allocated, but I got unexpected error when I close the program.

First, declaration in header file

```
class TileMapManager
{
public: 
     //Some public constructor, destructor and some functions...

private:
    // Other private data...
    int m_xSize;
    int m_ySize;
    int **m_mapSlots;

};
```

allocation below...

```
m_mapSlots = new int*[m_ySize];
    for (int i = 0; i < m_xSize; ++i)
        m_mapSlots[i] = new int[m_xSize];
```

and release function. I call it in the destructor.

```
void TileMapManager::ReleaseTilemap(void)
{
    ReleaseTileTexture();

    for (int y = 0; y < m_ySize; ++y)
        delete m_mapSlots[y]; // <- break!

    delete m_mapSlots;  
}
```

my program has been triggered break point in that line.

I think the way of deleting is alright, but I don't know why it causes problem.
Help me plz.

Comment: Do not add C tag for C++ questions! They are **different** languages.

Comment: `m_xSize` in one loop condition, `m_ySize` in the other. You're running out of bounds.

Comment: Another ill-advised attempt on incorrect emulation of 2-d array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure that

```
for (int i = 0; i < m_xSize; ++i)
```

shouldn't be

```
for (int i = 0; i < m_ySize; ++i)
```

?

If `m_xSize > m_ySize` undefined behavior may occur because

- `m_mapSlots` only points to `m_ySize` pointers
- `delete` will attempt to free unallocated memory

Comment: Just what we spoke about the other day. 2-D loop-allocated arrays are doomed to fail :)

Answer (score 1):

Never try to emulate 2-D arrays in such a fashion. Instead, define a 1-D vector of ints:

```
std::vector<int> m_mapSlots;
...
m_mapSlots.resize(m_ySize * m_xSize);

int v = m_MapSlots[x + y * x];
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong variable in your allocation:

```
m_mapSlots = new int*[m_ySize];   //    allocates m_ySize elements
for (int i = 0; i < m_xSize; ++i) // goes through m_xSize elements
    m_mapSlots[i] = new int[m_xSize];
```

The `m_xSize` in the loop condition should be `m_ySize`.

Or, you know, use `std::vector<int>` with a size of `m_xSize * m_ySize` and avoid the whole mess.